# Where are the colours of bluej syntax highlighting defined?

Tags: bluej

Where are the colours of the bluej editor syntax highlighting are defined, e.g. that /** comments are blue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the directory where BlueJ is installed (depends on your OS and how you installed it).
From there, you should notice a "stylesheet" folder. In this folder, you will find CSS files. The one that you seem to look for is "java-colors.css".